# One-to-one mapping vs one-to-one correspondence

Tags: functions, terminology

Does the phrase "one-to-one mapping" mean the same thing as "one-to-one correspondence?"  I know that the latter refers to a bijection.  Does the former refer to an injection (i.e. it is the same as simply "one-to-one") or does it, too, refer to a bijection?

Answer (score 10):

Typically, the former refers to injections, and the latter refers to bijections. A rather unfortunate bit of confusing terminology, that....

Comment: This is why we really should just stop using "one-to-one" and just say "bijection" or "injection".